# I can't Scroll my Screen when using SingleChildScollView in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-android, flutter-scrollbar

I am trying to make my main screen scrollable using SingleChildScrollView but it's not working as expected

here is my code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
            Row(...),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(...),
                    SizedBox(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, count) {
                          return Container(
                            height: 300,
                            child: Text("hi there $count"),
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: 4,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Comment: wrap with ```list view```

Answer (score 0):

change the column to `list view`

like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
            Row(...),
              Container(
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Text(...),
                    SizedBox(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, count) {
                          return Container(
                            height: 300,
                            child: Text("hi there $count"),
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: 4,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
```

try this code